# How to decode input field(data) of a transaction object?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions

I have tried with 
     web3.eth.decodeParameter(type,hexString) 
var input="0x0121b93f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004";
console.log(web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter('uint', input));

Expected output:4
but returns error "Cannot read property 'decodeParameter' of undefined"

Comment: The error is in the `eth.abi` not being present. can you share more about your js setup ? web3 version ?

Comment: @kaki-master-of-time
that question being asked by me as guest I have used "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.36" version